# Cocoa Touch - Floating Image bouncing across screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need help with making a UIImageView float on the screen and when it hits the walls it bounces off like collision detection..

I havent gotten further than making the imageview. I need some help..

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your life would be easier with a physics engine like chipmunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What is the best way to make a bouncing ball animation with infinite loop on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052878/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-bouncing-ball-animation-with-infinite-loop-on-ipho)