# Simple Animation for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I am currently developing an app for iPhone. I have finished most of it, and I'd like to have a 3D ball bouncing around on the screen whenever I tap a button. I've never worked with animation before can anyone point me to a nice simple tutorial or reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by various method.

You can use

1. Core Animation
2. Cocos 2D
3. Open GLES

If you are new to iOS programming, then you should probably go for

[Simple Ball Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052878/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-bouncing-ball-animation-with-infinite-loop-on-ipho)

[Ball Animations](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1793)

For Cocos 2d, a similar sample can be found at

1) [cocos2d-example-bouncing-ball](http://iphonedev.net/2009/05/10/cocos2d-example-bouncing-ball/)

2) [cocos2d-bouncing-ball-example](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2009/04/cocos2d-bouncing-ball-example/)